Will the air be low pressure above an airfoil going less than Mach 0.3?
If flow only becomes compressible (>5%) above Mach 0.3, and the only way for air to accelerate is by having a pressure gradient¹, will the air be low pressure on top of a wing going less than Mach 0.3?
So to explain that better, say you have a plane traveling Mach 0.2. The flow isn't compressible, hence, no air is being compressed. The way an airfoil works, (as I know) is when the air contacts the front portion of the airfoil, it compresses and therefore accelerates along the airfoil turning the air low pressure.
If the flow is not able to compress, then how does the air accelerate? The only way for air to accelerate is an adverse pressure gradient¹, which isn't possible below Mach 0.3.

¹: I'm not 100% that this is true, however I see no other way for air to accelerate. Seeing that I'm not sure, I might be mistaken.
Also, having a ‘pressure gradient’ might not be the correct wording. A pressure difference between 2 connected packages of air might be more accurate.

"when the air contacts the front portion of the airfoil, it compresses and therefore accelerates along the airfoil turning the air low pressure." That's not how it works. And you can have a change in pressure without compressibility. This happens in columns of water all the time.

@DavidK When the flow reaches the front of the airfoil, what else would it do if it didn’t accelerate? The air might not have a static pressure that is above ambient, but there does have to be a high pressure initially to accelerate the air, no?

There just needs to be a pressure differential. For example, ambient pressure far in front of the wing and a lower pressure above the wing.

@DavidK Right, but what is going to make that low pressure? Or how is that low pressure going to be made?

How does air accelerate?  Push it with higher pressure or pull it with lower pressure (or both).

That is not the way an airfoil works. To move through the air, you have to push the air out of the way. Newtons 3rd law says anything that gets pushed, pushes back. As you know, gravity is pulling you down all the time, but you have to push the air below you out of the way to actually start falling. If you, or your "airfoil" (or a brick) pushes that air down at least as hard as gravity, then you don't actually fall and that is called lift.

Understand that airflow is always compressible. The 0.3 Mach number is just a dividing line where compressibility effects are no longer a significant term. This allows for teaching simplification and what we all know as non-compressible flow. Make sure you have that concept clear. In the real-world if you are asked to go design X with a max velocity of 0.25 M -- you will be expected to consider all terms.


flow only becomes compressible above Mach 0.3... Say you have a plane traveling Mach 0.2. The flow isn't compressible... If the flow is not able to compress, then how does the air accelerate?

There's a mixing up of terminology at work here.
Pressure $p$ and density $\rho$ are two different physical quantities. Being a fluid incompressible only means that the changes in its density $\rho$ (and not pressure $p$) are negligible but this is not directly related to the changes of pressure around it - and viceversa. "Inviscid" might be a better wording.
The ubiquitous Bernoulli equation, for example, is strictly valid only for incompressible fluids:
$p+½\rho V^2=constant $
And it is more than enough to calculate the aerodynamic loads around a subsonic aircraft. If comprimibilty is no more negligible, then the compressible form of the Bernoulli equation is used:
$h+½V^2=constant $
where $h$ is the enthalpy.

I see. So even below Mach 0.3, the flow still has pressure changes big enough to make an effect?

@Wyatt: Insects fly

Well, we have a chicken and egg issue.
We know by Reynolds number analysis that there is indeed lower pressure above the wing where V is less than Mach 0.3.
Typically at Re = around 500,000 one has an increase in L/D ratio attributed to "top lift".
For a 1.5 meter wing, this would be around 5 meters/second or around 12 miles per hour!
So what accelerates the air?  The same thing that lifts the plane!

lower pressure created above the wing, above the Reynolds threshold, begins to accelerate the air

Lower than this, lift is only created by air deflecting off the bottom of the wing.  For a fixed geometry wing, the threshold is determined by velocity.
Air impacting the front of the wing at Mach < 0.3 is deflected away, not compressed.  The wing passes by the air molecules as they try to fill the void (lower pressure) above and behind (Angle of attack) the wing.
The air molecules accelerate downwards, but (ideally) never reach the wing (it has already gone by).  The result is downwash aft of the wing and an upforce (lift) on the wing.
